# How can I close the card if I press escape in a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to let the users press the escape key and close the card so that we can prevent loosing data in the form.
This is a child component and although I've applied the logic using a useEffect, I cannot close the card when pressing the escape key.
I don't know if the issue is due the card is fullwith, I mean the card is not a Modal or sth similar.
The function is the one that closes the card when clicking on the crossIcon button.

**The code:**

```
export const EditStyleCardHeader = (
  { isMoreSustainableChoice = false, isBi2Style, hasAllData }: EditStyleCardHeaderProps
): ReactElement => {
  const { setIsDrawerOpen, editStyleNumber, editStyleBrandNumber } = useStyleDialog();
  const { palette } = useTheme();


  const handleCloseEditCard = (): void => {
        setIsDrawerOpen(false);
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
      if (event.key === 'Escape') {
        handleCloseEditCard();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, [handleCloseEditCard]);

  return (
    <Stack
      direction="row"
      justifyContent="space-between"
      height={132}
      paddingLeft={9}
      paddingRight={10}
      minHeight={132}
      sx={{ borderBottom: `1px solid ${palette.divider}` }}
    >
      <Stack direction="row">
        <Stack direction='column' marginY={9}>
          <Stack direction='row' alignItems='center'>
            <CrossIcon
              style={{
                cursor: 'pointer',
                marginRight: 16,
              }}
              onClick={handleCloseEditCard}
            />
            <Typography variant="headings.h2">EDIT STYLE</Typography>
          </Stack>
          <Stack direction='row' marginTop={2} marginLeft={10}>
            <Typography
              marginRight={2}
              variant='body.default'
              sx={{ color: palette.text.secondary }}
            >
              {editStyleNumber}
            </Typography>
            {isMoreSustainableChoice && (
              <FashionForwardIcon
                color={palette.success.main}
              />
            )}
            {isBi2Style && hasAllData
              && <Chip size='small' label='BI2 Style' sx={{ marginLeft: 2 }} />}
          </Stack>
        </Stack>
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

Comment: Add output to console.log(event) in the handleKeyDown handler to ensure that the event occurs and event.key has the expected content.

Comment: yes, i've tested that and no console, so the useEffect isn't triggered. It should work but it doesn't that's why I was asking here so that I could get a solution.